# Rails adding background css to the matching results

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
@users = User.tagged_with(current_artist.tag_list, any: true)
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
     Tags: <%= user.tag_list.join(', ') %>
<% end %>
```

The above code displays all the users with one or more matching tags.
How can I add CSS background colour to the tags that matches. I tried the following and it kind of works but it creates an extra tag which i don't want.

```
<span style="background-color:red;"><%= current_user.tag_list & user.tag_list %></span>
```

Comment: `<%= user.tag_list.map{|t| "<span class='tag'>#{t}</span>" }.join(',').html_safe %>`

Comment: `.tag { background-color:red; }`

Comment: That highlights all the tags for that user instead of only the matching tags with current_user

Comment: I guess that you can modify with the logic you have added `current_user.tag_list & user.tag_list`

Comment: I'm nearly there. `<%= (current_artist.tag_list & user.tag_list).map{|t| "<span class='tag-cl'>#{t}</span>" }.join(',').html_safe %>`. This code works but i can only see matching tags.  I have to use this code`<%= user.tag_list.join(', ') %>` to display all the tags which again duplicates the tag twice.

Comment: Is there something similar like `<%= user.tag_list.join(', ') except current_artist.tag_list & user.tag_list%>` that i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= user.tag_list.map{|t| current_artist.tag_list.include?(t) ? "<span class='tag-cl'>#{t}</span>" : "#{t}" }.join(',').html_safe %>
```